# Excel Sheet created from ABAP using XML method throws error

Tags: excel, xml, abap

I'm trying to create an excel sheet and send it as an inbox/email attachment from an SAP background process using the xml method. I'm following the code/method described [here](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Formatted+Excel+as+Email+Attachment). I'm able to receive the inbox with an excel attachment but upon trying to open the attachment I get the following error message:

Problems came up in the following areas during load: 
Workbook Setting

This file cannot be opened because of errors. Errors are listed in: 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet files\Content.MSO\36F0E91E.log.

However, no log file actually exists at that location.

EDIT. I've found I can view the error log file by opening the path in a web browser. The error message given reads:

```
XML PARSE ERROR: Null or missing attribute value
  Error occurs at or below this element stack:
    <ss:Workbook>
```

Comment: Try saving the attachment to a folder and opening it from there. Hopefully the log file will end up in a more accessible location

Comment: I can't when I try to download The attachement from the SAP inbox I get a blank 'Download could not complete!' Error which makes me think it is the excel attachment itself which is malformed but I'm not sure how or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late reply, but have you considered the excellent library abap2xlsx that can be found on SDN code exchange? I believe that example 3 (ZDEMO_EXCEL3) in that package includes sending to email recipient.

Comment: That's actually the approach i went with in the end and worked very nicely so I'll mark this correct